# AnyView not re-rendering after state change

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I have the func below that returns AnyView and should give different results based on device orientation. When the orientation is changed, it is detected and printed, but the view is not re-rendered. Any idea how to fix this?

```
func getView() -> AnyView {
    @State var isPortrait = UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait

    let a =
        HStack {
            if isPortrait {
                VStack {
                    Text("text inside VStack")
                }
            } else {
                HStack {
                    Text("text inside HStack")
                }
            }
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
            print("notification isPortrait: \(UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait)")
            isPortrait = UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait
        }
        .onAppear() {
            isPortrait = UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait
        }
    return AnyView(a)
}
```

Comment: I think everything in your getView method should be contained in a custom View. isPortrait exists on the stack which is useless to your return value.

Comment: I agree with the above comment. isPortrait needs to be a property on a View to work. You should avoid AnyView when at all possible. In this case, it should be its own view, but if you are returning a View from a function look into how ViewBuilder works

Comment: try moving `@State var isPortrait = UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait` into the main view, eg `ContentView`. It seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my test code that shows the changing of orientations. Tested on ios 15, iPhone device.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
} 

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPortrait = UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait  // <--- here

    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 40) {
            Text("testing orientations")
            // getView()  // works just as well
            myView        // alternative without AnyView
        }
    }
    
    var myView: some View {
        Text(isPortrait ? "should be Portrait" : "should be Landscape")
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                isPortrait = UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait
            }
            .onAppear() {
                isPortrait = UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait
            }
    }
    
    func getView() -> AnyView {
        let a =
            HStack {
                if isPortrait {
                    VStack {
                        Text("should be Portrait")
                    }
                } else {
                    HStack {
                        Text("should be Landscape")
                    }
                }
            }
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                    print("notification isPortrait: \(UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait)")
                    isPortrait = UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait
            }
            .onAppear() {
                isPortrait = UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait
            }
        return AnyView(a)
    }
}
```

EDIT1:

As mentioned by @Rob, the best way is to make a separate custom view, such as:

```
struct GetView: View {
    @State var isPortrait = UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                if isPortrait {
                    VStack {
                        Text("should be Portrait")
                    }
                } else {
                    HStack {
                        Text("should be Landscape")
                    }
                }
            }
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                print("notification isPortrait: \(UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait)")
                isPortrait = UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait
            }
            .onAppear() {
                isPortrait = UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait
            }
        }
    }
}
```